# How to link cpprestsdk dynamically and boost statically using VcPkg?

Tags: visual-c++, vcpkg

I'm using VC2015 with vcpkg with MSBuild integration.
I have done:

```
.\vcpkg install cpprestsdk:x86-windows
```

Now my project is using dlls of cpprestsdk and its dependencies.
Is it possible to use cpprestsdk dll and link to static libs of its dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the triplet file (`triplets\x86-windows.cmake`) or create a new one that specifies the precise combination of settings you'd like.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/80f64c24dc0513b053f431059bc50634321702e7/docs/users/triplets.md#per-port-customization

Comment: Can the triplet be solution/project specific? in case another project wants different configuration.

Comment: In that case, it's easiest to have two separate vcpkg repos; though it's also possible to have two different triplets in the same repo.